# Configure a JMS (ActiveMQ) queue so that it only contains the last message

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We have quartz process that polls a ActiveMQ JMS queue.

We know that we could get several messages a minute would like to only respond to the most current message at a configured polling rate of a minute or more.

We don't need to process any of the previous messages.

Is there a way to configure the queue to get this behavior?

Its seems like a topic has the ability to do this via the subscription recovery policy using a count of 1. We would like to do this using a queue to guarantee (more or less) a single delivery of the message.

Or is there a conceptual flaw in our assumptions...

Thanks

Comment: That's not really the use case for JMS. It sounds like you need a database...

Comment: In WebSphere MQ it would be easy as pie.  Publish retained publications as persistent messages.  The topic always holds the latest one and it is hardened to disk in two places.  Does Active MQ have something similar to WMQ's retained pubs?  If not, is there any WMQ in your shop that you could leverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there is no standard operation for this, so you will have to write some code....

One possible solution would be to use a *QueueBrowser* together with a *QueueReceiver*:

Through the *QueueReceiver* you would get an Enumeration of the messages in the queue. For each message you can now perform a receive with a MessageSelector on the JMSMessageID as long as *hasMoreElements()* returns true. The last message will be the one you want to have....

Answer (score 0):

When using activemq, you can use "image caching" on topics. One of the settings there is to always keep the last mesage sent..

Take a look at the Subscription recovery Policy settings:

http://activemq.apache.org/subscription-recovery-policy.html